# Anouncement for german area on building and contructing

Tags: discussion

I invite all **german speaking** architects, builders and house owners to join the discussion

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47602/bauwesen

I hope it is OK to use meta.diy.SX for this anouncement.

Please support the new QA Base with good questions, votes and by following it.

Comment: Proposal has been deleted. But join my DIY site for Germany DIY enthusiasts - also see [my question](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/812/should-there-be-a-german-diy-qa-site).

Comment: this page disappeared too. But why?